# Programatically added imageView in collection view is showing as garbage while changing it from landscape to portrait mode

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have added the imageview and label programatically in collection view cell, It is showing in portrait mode perfectly for the first time and when i change the orientation from landscape to portrait It is not showing perfectly, showing as overlapped on the same image.I have written the following code in collectionview cell for rowat indexpath.
 »»»»»»» help me out from this problem

```
UILabel *titleLable;
UIImageView *ImageView;
int sectionValue=(int)collectionView.tag;
GDColVwCell*cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CVCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


ImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0,self.view.frame.size.width-40, heightForImageView)];
titleLable=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, ImageView.frame.size.height-50, self.view.frame.size.width-40, 50)];


titleLable.text= [[[[titleNamesArr objectAtIndex:sectionValue] objectForKey:@"videos"]  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];


titleLable.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;


  titleLable.numberOfLines=2;

    titleLable.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:17];
  titleLable.backgroundColor=[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];

titleLable.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];




NSString *imgString=[[[[titleNamesArr objectAtIndex:sectionValue] objectForKey:@"videos"]  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"thumb"];
NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:imgString];
NSLog(@"USE PROFILE IMAGE URL IN ViewDidLoad=>%@",url);


[ImageView sd_setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[ UIImage imageNamed:@"logo"]];


cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:ImageView];
[cell.contentView addSubview:titleLable];

return cell;
```